# [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available when inventory exists

Tags: azure, ansible

I'm trying to get a list of facts available about my azure VM by running

```
ansible -m setup hostname
```

as described in the [FAQ](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-see-a-list-of-all-of-the-ansible-variables)

So I have

```
ansible -m setup my-vm1
```

which I run from the machine in the azure cloud that I normally run my ansible commnads from (the machine I normally successfully use to talk to and modify the host in question) This results in:

```
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available
```

However I have an ansible inventory in /etc/ansible/hosts:

```
40.127.174.129
my-vm1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com ansible_sudo_pass=MyPassword
my-vm2.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
my-vm3.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
```

When I run the same command using the FQDN I get the following:

```
[me@ansible-machine]$ ansible -m setup my-vm1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com

my-vm1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com | UNREACHABLE! => {
"changed": false,
"msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
"unreachable": true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed

```
ansible -m setup hostname -u username
```

where username was the user to login with on the remote host!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you haven't mentioned how are you authenticating to the hosts. Are you able to SSH in to the server you are trying to setup ? Ansible tries to ssh into the server on port 22 by default, if you are using a custom ssh port you may want to define custom ports on your inventory file.

Second thing would be checking credentials, are you using key based authentication ? If yes try to do ssh username@yourazureinstance and see if it works. If you are using password based authentication, please set the credentials on inventory file or you can use `--ask pass` parameter for the ssh password.

[Refer this link for more info](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html)

Comment: Yes I can ssh to the server from outside the cloud using username password authentication. From the ansible machine in the cloud I have sshkeys set up and that's how the ansible commands work. In some tasks I use 'become' and the ansible_sudo_pass in the inventory comes into play then. I can also ssh into the target machine from the ansible machine using ssh me@my-vm1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com as you suggest.

Comment: Are you able to ssh to the azure instance from your ansible server? Try setting up ansible_ssh_private_key_file variable and see if that helps.

`your_azure_host          ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/example/.ssh/aws.pem`

Comment: Yes I can ssh to the azure target machine from the ansible machine (also in azure) using ssh me@my-vm1.... and I get a session. Addind the ansible_ssh_private_key_file variable to the inventory didn't help.